# How do I show text boxes in one line vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a form

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>From<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker" name="date1"></p>
    <p>To<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker2" name="date2"></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

and my css is

```
input[type="text"], textarea, input[type="file"] { 
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
```

Which shows the form on web like this:

[image]

`To` Textbox is slightly back than the `From` Textbox
I want to show both textboxs in-line using css. Help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the names in a `label` tag and assign some fixed `width` to the label element, this way, your textboxes will be inline vertically and also the names of the textboxes will make sense and will be accessible in a better way as far as screen readers or other such devices are concerned.

```
form p label {
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbzkD/)</kbd>

Though, I don't think this is a wise way to achieve so, generally form elements are nothing but a list of informative textboxes where we ask the users, their information.

So it is much logical to use `ul` and `li` or nothing but a `div` instead of <s>`p`</s> elements because you incase if it happened that you need an extra b*lock level element* for some reason, you cannot nest it inside `p` tag, that's *invalid markup*.

Comment: [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/38hHz/1/) - I was just creating an answer and made the fiddle so you can have it xD

Comment: Thanks alot Mr Alien and Mr Ruddy. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO Semantically, you should use `<label>` and the good old `<br/>` instead of `<p>`
And set a common width for the label

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
 <label for='popupDatepicker'>From</label>
 <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker" name="date1" /><br/>
 <label for='popupDatepicker2'>To</label>
 <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker2" name="date2" /><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>

label{
 display:inline-block; // by default label is inline, which won't take height and width
 width:100px;
}
input[type="text"], textarea, input[type="file"] {
 background-color: green;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Tr392/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use label tags instead of paragraphs and then you should use tables like this: (this is you final code)

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <table>
            <tr><td><label>From</label></td><td><input type="text" id="popupDatepicker" name="date1"></td>
            <tr><td><label>To</label></td><td><input type="text" id="popupDatepicker2" name="date2"></td>
    </table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p>To<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker2" name="date2" style="
    margin-left: 19px;
"></p>
```